# Deleting another user's files

Tags: linux

Some files are automatically published to a folder on my machine by a scheduled job. The nature of the job is such that the files get published with the owner as `xyz`.

Now I need to create a Python script that processes these files and then deletes them afterwards. My user is `abc`. Of course if the script is not run as root, I do not have permission to delete or make changes to these files.

Is there a way to make the user `abc` able to delete/make changes to anything owned by user `xyz`? I *do* have root access.

Answer (score 3):

You could ...

1. change the scheduled job to `chown` the files as a last step
2. put both users in the same group and then make the scheduled job create the files with appropriate group permissions (`chmod`)
3. use `sudo` to delete the files

Depending on your usecase, the easiest part would be no 1.